# vba - selection of cell references of empty cells in a row

Tags: excel, vba

Via the following code

```
Sub Macro1()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select

End Sub
```

I can select the empty cells in a row. Is there a way to retrieve all cell references of these cells? With cell references I mean x and y in

```
Cells(x,y)
```

Comment: Put your code here

Comment: I do not know how to code it. Hence I cannot add my code ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it: -

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cl  As Range

Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select

Set Rng = Selection
    For Each Cl In Rng.Cells
        Debug.Print "Row: " & Cl.Row & ", Column: " & Cl.Column
    Next
Set Rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Your line of code selected what you wanted, the code references that selection as `Rng` using `Selection`. It then loops through each item in `Rng` as `Cl`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Select` and `Selection` in Gary's answer are not recommend. Consider using the below for a more concise and efficient method of achieving the same thing.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim Cl  As Range

For Each cl In Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells
    Debug.Print "Row: " & Cl.Row & ", Column: " & Cl.Column
Next

End Sub
```